# How do I best implement a Derived with members depending on a Template Parameter Pack Specialization?

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-specialization, parameter-pack

## Goal

I want to implement a struct `Derived<size_t ...Tpar>`, satisfying certain requirements. I have a functioning solution code, but it has certain disadvantages. I seek a better way of doing it.

## Requirements

`Derived<size_t ...Tpar>` must inherit exclusively from `Base<size_t ...Tpar>`.
The relevant cases for me are `Derived<size_t>` and `Derived<>`.

Members and attributes:

- an identical member function `void a(void);` for empty and non-empty Tpar
- an array `data` of length `Tpar[0]` for `Derived<Tpar...>` for non-empty Tpar only
- and a function `void b(void);` for non-empty Tpar only, that performs computations on `data`.

## Minimum working example

As the comments in the example code below indicate, **these issues** make the solution unappealing:

1. Since `Derived<>` and `Derived<size_t>` both implement `a()`, I thought of inheriting `Derived<size_t>` from `Derived<>`. But this does not work because `Derived<size_t>` would inherit from `Base<>`, which is against requirement.
2. I hence opted for a specialized Submodule. But this does not work because Derived is already a template, hence I cannot specialize a submodule template within its namespace as per the rules of the language.
3. I thus make the Submodule in two non-template explicit variants and employ `conditional_t` to obtain the right type of submodule in either `Derived` specialization.
   3.1. Is there a better alternative for the array (that I have to augment with a zero only for the conditional to not complain that `aTpar[0]` is a null-pointer?
   3.2. Is there a way for templating the submodule or making the entire code shorter, without exposing the Submodule to the compilation unit?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<type_traits>

template<size_t ...Tpar> class Base{};

// I cannot inherit Derived<Tpar> from Derived<> since this would make Derived<Tpar> a derived of Base<>.
template<size_t ...Tpar>
class Derived: Base<Tpar...>{
    // c++ won't allow template structure specializations within a template struct
    template<size_t n>
    struct SubModule_paged{
        double data[n];
        void foo(){
            // foo is a routine that computes on data.
            std::cout << "Sub<"<<n<<">foo.\n";
        }
    };
    struct SubModule_empty{
        // no data, hence no foo.
        void foo() = delete; // COMPILER HINT: Intentionally, Derived<> has no member b.
    };
    static constexpr size_t nTpar = sizeof...(Tpar);
    static constexpr std::array<const size_t, nTpar+1> aTpar = {Tpar...,0}; // <-- This is ugly!
    using SubModuleType = std::conditional_t< (nTpar>0) , SubModule_paged<aTpar[0]> , SubModule_empty >;
    //
    SubModuleType sub;
    //
public:
    void a(){
        std::cout << "a.\n";
    }
    void b(){
        std::cout << "b.\n";
        sub.foo();
    }
};

int main(){
    Derived< > x;
    Derived<3> y;
    
    x.a();
    //x.b();
    
    y.a();
    y.b();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> an identical member function `void a(void);` for empty and non-empty `Tpar`

Ok, `a` should be member of `Base`.

> an array data of length `Tpar[0]` for `Derived<Tpar...>` for non-empty `Tpar` only
> and a function void `b(void);` for non-empty `Tpar` only, that performs computations on data.

Ok, specialize `Derived` for when `Tpar...` is at least one argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<size_t ...Tpar> struct Base{
    void a(void) {}
};

// base template
template <size_t ...Tpar> struct Derived : public Base<Tpar...> {};

// specialization for one or more size_t 
template <size_t Tfirst,size_t ...Tpar> struct Derived<Tfirst,Tpar...> : public Base<Tfirst,Tpar...> {
    std::array<size_t,Tfirst> arr;
    void b() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived<> d;
    //d.b(); error
    //d.arr; error
    Derived<42> e;
    e.b();
    e.arr;
}
```

Maybe you will not agree about making `a` a member of `Base`, but the thing about distinguising between empty and non empty `Tpar...` is actually rather simple. You only need to consider that `size_t Tfirst,size_t ...Tpar` is one or more argument, while `size_t Tpar...` is zero or more. I think you got confused by thinking about the parameter pack like an array where you need to pick the first element via `Tpar[0]`. But a parameter pack is not an array and no array is needed to pick the first element either.

Comment: Thanks. I learnt that ``template <size_t ...Tpar> struct Derived : public Base<Tpar...> {};`` is possible and still specializing without that meaning that two specializations of Base are inherited. I am quite unsure about indeed making a() a member of base. One could put a layer inbetween to delete a so it does not shine through in all other classes that inherit from base. Is there maybe something better than a layer over base?

Comment: @Kaisong you mean there are other types inheriting from `Base` that do not need `a` ?

Comment: @Aconcagua I _would_ agree, if a() was not multiple complex functions. Probably best might have been all along to inherit all deriveds from yet a second base that implements a(). --- basically that's what your answer proposes via base. So I mark that as solution.

Comment: I sense complexity that you did not explain to us. Note that design does not emerge out of nowhere but from concrete requirements. "better" doesnt mean a thing when you do not say what it means.  I can only take into account the three bullets you mentioned in the question.